# share information between function(BPF/XDP)

Tags: ebpf, bpf, bcc-bpf, xdp-bpf

Objective: If process id/name = xxx then drop the packet
So, I am bit confused. So far I know you can't extract process information from XDP but bpf trace allows you to trace it.
Here's my probable solution, use bpf hash maps to share information between two function. If process name == xx then XDP_DROP. (This maybe wrong, but something I was trying)

But I am confused how to use BPF_HASHMAPS, I read the documentation on bcc yet..

Example: From this hello function I can trace events

```
struct data_t {
    u32 pid;
    u64 ts;
    char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
};
BPF_PERF_OUTPUT(events);
int hello(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    struct data_t data = {};
    data.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    data.ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
    bpf_get_current_comm(&data.comm, sizeof(data.comm));
    events.perf_submit(ctx, &data, sizeof(data));
    return 0;
}
```

XDP function to drop packer

```
int udpfilter(struct xdp_md *ctx) {

  bpf_trace_printk("got a packet\n");
  //u32 cpu = bpf_get_smp_processor_id();
  //bpf_trace_printk("%s looking\n",cpu);
  //u32 pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
  
  return XDP_DROP;
}
```

Now how do I fetch pid value and use it in XDP function, plus does the solution even makes any sense. Thanks for the help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you know eBPF programs can be loaded into the kernel at different locations. XDP programs are loaded just after the network driver and just before the network stack. At this point the kernel doesn't know for which process a packet might be since it will figure all of that out in the network stack.

The `hello` program you are showing is an example of a kprobe(kernel probe). It attaches to whatever kernel function you specify, but it is a tracing tool, can't make changes.

Also, some helper functions like `bpf_get_current_pid_tgid` are program type dependent. `bpf_get_current_pid_tgid` only works in kprobes, uprobes, tracepoint programs (perf programs), the may actually also work in socket and cGroup programs, the issue is that there is not a very clear list or overview of which work where, these are two good but non-comprehensive links:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/bpf-in-depth-bpf-helper-functions
- https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/kernel-versions.md#program-types

In the end it comes down to logic. The kernel can only give you access to data and actions it has access to itself. So if you want to do network related things based on process ID's you might need to use an eBPF program attached at a location where such info is available(keep in mind that this is obviously also slower).

So depending on what exactly you want to do you have a few options:

- Attach an eBPF program to a network socket(`BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER`) so you can filter packets on the socket level. This does require the program that creates the socket to attach the program to it.
- Use a cGroup and `BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SKB` program to block packets. Since you attach the program to the cGroup, this doesn't require cooperation from the program.
- Use an TC program(`BPF_PROG_TYPE_SCHED_ACT`), on this level a packet is already parsed, but you still need to match it to a process
- Use an XDP program(`BPF_PROG_TYPE_XDP`) can still be used, this does require you to parse all layers of the network packet(Ethernet, VLAN, IP, UDP/TCP), and then manually extract the protocol, Destination IP, and Destination port. Just like in the TC program you then need to match it to an pid using a lookup table.

When going the XDP or TC route you need to create this lookup table. As far as I know you can't access the table of the kernel via helper functions. A few approaches are:

- parsing the output of `netstat -lpn`(protocol, destination ip, destination port and PID) and setting the data in a map to be used by a program
- Getting the same data but directly from /sys or /proc(I don't know where the data is stored exactly)
- Recording which PIDs have which sockets during creation(using a second program(kprobe/tracepoint)) and setting this data in a map shared by both the XDP/TC program and the trace program. (not quite sure how to share maps between programs in BCC, but it is certainly possible when using libbpf)

Comment: Thanks alot for breaking down your answer!
1. I tried using ```BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER``` in past; but only information I can get was IP(TO, From), protocol etc. but could not extract program name from packet.
2. This is straight forward, create a CG group and push the program to specific cggroup and drop all the packets.
3 & 4 I guess requires me to research a bit.

Thanks man! Thanks for breakdown.